# Why does this segfault on MacOS Ventura 13.4 on an M2 Max MBP and Qt 6.5.1?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am using Qt 6.5.1 for MacOS.  The following code segfaults when I send the process a SIGTERM on MacOS Ventura 13.4 on an M2 Max MBP:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <signal.h>

static QTcpServer* server {};

static void
signal_handler(int sig)
{
    qInfo() << "got termination signal; closing server socket...";
    server->close();
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    server = new QTcpServer(&a);
    a.connect(server, &QTcpServer::newConnection, &a, []() {
        qInfo() << "got client connection";
        auto client = server->nextPendingConnection();
        client->deleteLater();
    });

    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 5150);
    qInfo() << "listening for connections...";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Code works fine on a Debian Linux arm64 box.  And by fine, I mean "doesn't segfault".

Doing a backtrace on the core file, I get the following:

```
* thread #1, stop reason = ESR_EC_DABORT_EL0 (fault address: 0x20)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010133aaac QtCore`QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::markPendingSocketNotifiers() + 144
    frame #1: 0x000000010133afe4 QtCore`QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::activateSocketNotifiers() + 28
    frame #2: 0x000000010133ba24 QtCore`QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 888
    frame #3: 0x00000001011d98fc QtCore`QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 532
    frame #4: 0x00000001011d0614 QtCore`QCoreApplication::exec() + 112
    frame #5: 0x00000001001c43b8 segvtest`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fc3f650) at main.cpp:33:12
    frame #6: 0x000000018fecff28 dyld`start + 2236
```

Is this a bug in Qt or am I screwing something up here?

Comment: The things that can be done inside a signal handler are **heavily constrained**.  I'm 99.44% sure your handler violates the constraints.  (On my platform, `man sigaction` lists the very small subset of functions that can be called during signal handler.)

Comment: @Eljay looks like you might be right.  I modified that sample code to trigger the server->close() from the newConnection slot instead, and it works fine. For full disclosure, in the real code I made a class that basically "converts" a UNIX signal into a Qt signal so that I can use a slot to handle it.  Worked fine on Linux, but I guess not so much on MacOS.  Which I guess means it only works on Linux out of sheer luck and it might stop working in the future.